# Computing a prior from two components in Naive Bayes

Tags: naive-bayes, expectation-maximization, dirichlet-distribution, generative-models, semi-supervised-learning

Given a model parameter $\theta$ that is composed of two distributions in a Naive Bayes classifier, how is $P(\theta)$ typically computed in practice?

More specifically, from the article of Nigam et al 2006 ([pdf link](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Etom/pubs/NigamEtAl-bookChapter.pdf)), $\theta$ is two Dirichlet distributions: one for words $w_t$conditioned on classes $c_j$ denoted $\theta_{{w_t|c_j}}$ and the other for overall class probas denoted $\theta_{c_j}$.

The questions is: how to compute the term
$\log(P(\theta))$ appearing in Equation 3.8?

E.g., is there an implicit factorization assumption in this article so that we have a product $P(\theta) = P(\theta_{{w_t|c_j}}).P(\theta_{c_j})$ ?
If so, then we have

$\log(P(\theta)) = \log(P(\theta_{{w_t|c_j}})) + \log(P(\theta_{c_j}))$ which is simple to compute since each term on the right hand side is itself a log of products, i.e. sums of probabilities from Equations 3.5 and 3.6.

Conversely, if there is not a factorization assumption how is $\log(P(\theta))$ computed in this setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be an implicit assumption that $P(\theta_{w_t | c_j}) = P(\theta_{w_t | c_j} | \theta_{c_j})$. Then using the identity $P(A,B) = P(A|B)P(B)$ we have the third equality in $P(\theta) = P(\theta_{w_t | c_j}, \theta_{c_j}) = P(\theta_{w_t | c_j}|\theta_{c_j}) P(\theta_{c_j}) = P(\theta_{w_t|c_j})P(\theta_{c_j})$